# Newbie stumped by selection.sort

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to JavaScript and to D3. I have bar charts working with (too many) animations, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to sort the data so the bar charts ascend or descend in size, much less write a function that allows the user to re-sort. I've tried variations of .sort(function(a,b){return a.value - b.value;}) all over the place, but honestly I don't even know where in the chain to put it, or if it's the right command. I need an example, please!

Given this bar chart below, taken from the Scott Murray tutorial on D3, how would I sort the chart before it first appears? And how would I resort it? Does merely resorting the dataset automatically redraw all the svg elements, or do you need to resort the dataset and then write code to redraw the elements? (You can see, total beginner at work here!)

```
//Width and height
var w = 500;
var h = 100;
var barPadding = 1;

var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("x", function(d, i) {
return i * (w / dataset.length);
})
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d * 4);
})
.attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
.attr("height", function(d) {
    return d * 4;
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated

John

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using d3 sort in a code snippet. If you would like, you can read more about this in the documentation they provide.

Sort method for d3.js:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#sort

Sort as part of the javascript default Web API methods:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```js
  dataSet = [{
    text: 'cancel',
    index: 0,
    icon: 'images/cancel.svg',
    callback: function() {
      _this.cancel()
    }
  }, {
    text: 'previous',
    index: 5,
    icon: 'images/prev-avail.svg',
    callback: function() {
      _this.previousSegment();
    }
  }, {
    text: 'next',
    index: 2,
    icon: 'images/next-avail.svg',
    callback: function() {
      _this.nextSegment()
    }
  }, {
    text: 'nextAdded',
    index: 2,
    icon: 'images/example.svg',
    callback: function() {
      _this.nextSegment()
    }
  }];

  $('#div1').html(JSON.stringify(dataSet));

  dataSet.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.index - b.index
  });

  $('#div2').html(JSON.stringify(dataSet));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<br/>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to sort the data, or am I missing something here?

```
var dataset = [...];

dataset.sort(function(a,b){ 
    return a - b; 
});

// Create SVG element
// ...
```

Comment: Yes I just want to sort, but also re-sort using transitions when a button is clicked. I thought I needed to perform the sort *after* the data is selected with d3.selectall.data. If I do it before, as you suggest, how do I re-sort the bar chart without having to redraw everything from scratch? I'm probably just confusing myself.

Comment: You should be able to rebind the new (sorted) data, and then update all the attributes of your bars. Does this help?  http://jsfiddle.net/findango/94vxf/1/

Comment: I've read somewhere about a way to just sort the selection, sort of like (in this example) svg.sort(comparator) but I've not been able to make it work. Your example looks like something I might be able to understand. thanks heaps! John

Comment: OK, I see what you're thinking. Calling selection.sort() reorders the elements of the selection in the DOM -- this doesn't necessarily change anything visually. If you want to move the existing rectangles to a different position in the image, you need to select them and transition their x and y attributes to that new position. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks findango. I'm beginning to realise that my confusion actually arises from the fact that my data is sourced from an ajax post function, which means all of my rendering has to be done inside of the ajax success handler. I can't figure out how a "sort" button in the html can interact with the success handler. Can a button call a sort function inside the handler? How would it see such a function? If you wouldn't mind tweaking your example, could you point me in the right direction? thanks

Comment: If you want to put up an example that's not working for you, I'll take a look. In general, I think you want a render() function like my example which you can call from both the success handler and from the button click.

Comment: Once I got my head around asynchronous functions, I was able to use all your tips and I now have it working fine. Thanks a million for your help! John